# Python, tkinter: How to identify positions of items in a grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok, so I have this code that will generate a grid of buttons within a tkinter window, but I have no way of telling apart the buttons in the grid. Say if I wanted to make the button in grid position (4,4) blue, how would I do that? Do I need to use a list? I'm sure it's a quick fix, thanks in advance.

```
def game(width,height):

    for x in range(width):

        for y in range(height):

            square = Button(gameWindow)
            square.grid(column = x, row = (y + 1), sticky = (N+S+E+W))

    for x in range(width):

        Grid.columnconfigure(gameWindow, x, weight = 1)

    for y in range(height):

        Grid.rowconfigure(gameWindow, (y + 1), weight = 1)

    gameWindow.mainloop()

game(8,8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `square` objects in a list of lists, then you can reference each object by the indexes of `x` and `y`

```
from Tkinter import *

def game(width,height):
    for x in range(width):
        # fill a row in the list
        squares.append([None] * height)

        for y in range(height):
            squares[-1][y] = Button(gameWindow)
            squares[-1][y].grid(column = x, row = (y + 1), sticky = (N+S+E+W))

    for x in range(width):

        Grid.columnconfigure(gameWindow, x, weight = 1)

    for y in range(height):

        Grid.rowconfigure(gameWindow, (y + 1), weight = 1)

squares = []
gameWindow = Tk()

game(8,8)

# change color of square in x=3, y=4
squares[3][4].configure(bg='blue')

gameWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do this? I'm not that familiar with lists. Thanks

Comment: Edited with an example

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestions:**
If you are thinking of visually differentiating the grids, you can use the Button's background, activebackground, and image options in addition to mike.k's suggestion. The activebackground option gives contrast at where the mouse pointer is and easiet to implement. Furthermore, you can devise a clever system to display colour in relations to your grid system.

**Amended your code to demo implementation:**

```
from tkinter import *

def game(width,height,gameWindow):

    colors = ['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'white',
              'black', 'brown', 'purple', 'cyan']

    for x in range(width):

        for y in range(height):

            color = colors[y]
            print('color = {}'.format(color))
            square = Button(gameWindow, background=color,
                            activebackground='gold')
            square.grid(column = x, row = (y + 1), sticky = (N+S+E+W))

    for x in range(width):
        Grid.columnconfigure(gameWindow, x, weight = 1)

    for y in range(height):
        Grid.rowconfigure(gameWindow, (y + 1), weight = 1)

gameWindow = Tk()
game(8,8, gameWindow)
gameWindow.mainloop()
```

**Outcome from code**:
[image]